# Search and Display Result from Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new in php. I'm trying to show some results from SQL Database using php.

I've a search form that contains 3 fields. When user will submit this form, if search value match with database it will show some result. If search value don't match with database it'll show an error message.

```
<form method="post">
  <label>User ID</label>  
  <input name="textinput" type="text" value="">

  <label>Username</label>  
  <input name="textinput" type="text" value="">

  <label>Country</label>
    <select name="selectbasic">
      <option value="">Country 1</option>
      <option value="">Country 2</option>
      <option value="">Country 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my database rows

```
user_id;
user_name
user_email
full_name
country
division
user_bio
```

Result will show like this...

```
User ID: 123
Username: XYZ
User Email: xyz
Full Name: xyz
Country: xyz
Division: xyz
User Bio: xyz
```

please give me a best solution to solve this issue.

here is my code but this code show result only when user_id match but i need to match 3 fields

```
<?php
$output = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","dbuser","password","dbname");

    $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

    $resultsSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id = '$search'");

    if($resultsSet->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rows = $resultsSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
           $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
           $user_name = $rows['user_name'];
           $user_email = $rows ['user_email'];
           $full_name = $rows ['full_name'];
           $country = $rows ['country'];
           $division = $rows ['division'];
           $user_bio = $rows ['user_bio'];

           $output = "
          <td>$user_id</td>
          <td>$user_name</td>
          <td>$user_email</td>
          <td>$full_name</td>
          <td>$country</td>
          <td>$division</td>
          <td>$user_bio</td>";
        }
    }else{
            $output = "No results";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least how's your connection to database is written?

Comment: What you are looking for is very simple to do small question are you looking to do it without having to reload the page?

Comment: Yes i tried before ask this question. But i only able to search only one field, $resultsSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id = '$search'"); but i don't know how to search 3 field.

Comment: You only need to pull information where user_id = $id the rest will automatically be pulled from where ever the sql calls and then you can display $row = $resultsSet->fetch_assoc(); 
$row['Division']; etc

Comment: You can select more fields with an `AND` operator.
Example: `SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id = '$search' AND user_name = '$username' AND country = '$country'`

Comment: so where are your variables and POST arrays and mysql?

Comment: well in either case; someone popped an answer down there, see that. Personally, I think the question is too broad.

Comment: Seeing your edit now, this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` won't happen and error reporting would have told you about it.

Comment: my code added in main question, please take a look.

Comment: Please check my comment for the `AND` operator. Have you tried that?

Comment: @FrankM yes tried your suggestion but no solution found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue. Here is my code

```
<?php
$output = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //Connect to the database
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","dbuser","password","dbname");

    $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $country = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

    //Query the database
    $resultsSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id = '$search' AND user_name = '$username' AND country = '$country'");

    if($resultsSet->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rows = $resultsSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
       $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
       $user_name = $rows['user_name'];
       $user_email = $rows ['user_email'];
       $full_name = $rows ['full_name'];
       $country = $rows ['country'];
       $division = $rows ['division'];
       $user_bio = $rows ['user_bio'];

           $output = "
      <td>$user_id</td>
      <td>$user_name</td>
      <td>$user_email</td>
      <td>$full_name</td>
      <td>$country</td>
      <td>$division</td>
      <td>$user_bio</td>";
        }
    }else{
            $output = "No Results Found";
    }

}
?>
```

Search form

```
<form method="post">
  <label>User ID</label>  
  <input name="search" type="text" value="">

  <label>Username</label>  
  <input name="username" type="text" value="">

  <label>Country</label>
    <select name="country">
      <option value="">Country 1</option>
      <option value="">Country 2</option>
      <option value="">Country 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the connection with the database.

Here is an example:

```
try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname = your_databasename","user","password");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
   echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage() . "\n" ;
   die();
}
```

Then you need to add the results of your form into a query.

Example:

```
$db = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id=? AND user_name=? AND country=?');
$db->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT, 30);
$db->bindParam(2, $_REQUEST["name"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
$db->bindParam(3, $_REQUEST["country"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
$db->execute();
$data = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

The name between the "[ ]" after $_REQUEST is the name parameter from the

As last you need to write the code to output the results.

Something like:

```
echo "user id:".$data[user_id];
....
```

Comment: i added my code with main question can you please see that.

Comment: I think that you need to change the name parameters from the <INPUT ... to unique values and then use $_POST['...'] with between the '[ ]' the unique value of the parameter u need.. and then u can use; SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id = '$_post['id']' AND user_name = '$_POST['username']");